# Show image in panel

Tags: python

I'd like to show an image (png, preferably) in my panel. Does anyone know if this is supported through labels or template_XX UIPanels?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only option is to use a texture preview, which requires an Image and a Texture ID datablock (`Texture.image = Image`). It can then be added to the layout by using:

```
layout.template_preview(bpy.data.textures["Tex"])
```

But there's no control about how it's drawn (not even the vertical size using `UILayout.scale_y`).